# drop duplicated and concat pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
'id': ["1", "2", "1", "3", "3", "4"],
'date': ["2017", "2011", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018"],
'code': ["CB25", "CD15", "CZ10", None, None, "AZ51"],
'col_example': ["22", None, "22", "55", "55", "121"],
'comments': ["bonjour", "bonjour", "bonjour", "hola", "Hello", None]
```

Result:

```
  id   date  code      col_example   ....       comments
0  1   2019  CB25/CZ10          22   ....        bonjour (and not bonjour // bonjour)
1  2   2011  CD15             None   ....        bonjour
2  3   2017  None               55   ....  hola // Hello
3  4   2018  AZ51              121   ....           None
```

I want to keep a single id

If two ids are the same, I would like:

If comments = None and = str: Keep only the comments which are not None (example: id = 1, keep the comments "hello")
If two comments = str: Concaten the two comments with a "//" (example id = 3, comments = "hola // hello")

For the moment I tried with sort_value, and drop_duplicate without success

thank you

Comment: Can you add expected output DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) by column `comments` and then [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), last add [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace empty strings to `None` rows:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('id')
         .agg({'date': 'last',
               'comments': lambda x: ' // '.join(x.dropna())})
         .replace({'comments': {'': None}})
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
  id  date       comments
0  1  2019        bonjour
1  2  2011        bonjour
2  3  2017  hola // Hello
3  4  2018           None
```

EDIT: For avoid removed all columns is necessary aggregate all of them, you can create dictionary for aggregation dynamic like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ["1", "2", "1", "3", "3", "4"],
'date': ["2017", "2011", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018"],
'code': ["CB25", "CD15", "CB25", None, None, "AZ51"],
'col_example': ["22", None, "22", "55", "55", "121"],

'comments': [None, "bonjour", "bonjour", "hola", "Hello", None]})
print (df)
  id  date  code col_example comments
0  1  2017  CB25          22     None
1  2  2011  CD15        None  bonjour
2  1  2019  CB25          22  bonjour
3  3  2013  None          55     hola
4  3  2017  None          55    Hello
5  4  2018  AZ51         121     None

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id','comments']), 'last')
d['comments'] = lambda x: ' // '.join(x.dropna())
print (d)
{'code': 'last', 'col_example': 'last', 'date': 'last', 
       'comments': <function <lambda> at 0x000000000ECA99D8>}

df1 = (df.groupby('id')
         .agg(d)
         .replace({'comments': {'': None}})
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
  id  code col_example  date       comments
0  1  CB25          22  2019        bonjour
1  2  CD15        None  2011        bonjour
2  3  None          55  2017  hola // Hello
3  4  AZ51         121  2018           None
```

Comment: thx for the answer.
it work, but if a id have a comments = None, i dont have the id in the df1 ...
example: id = 3 and comments = None
result: i dont have id = 3 and comments = None

Comment: thank you so much
And if I want to keep the column 'col2' ?

Comment: @Eolynas - oops, I miss it.

Comment: @Eolynas - What is logic for `date`s? Because for `id=1` it is first `date` per `id` and for `id=3` it is last date.

Comment: No real logic ... is the just a example, sorry ^^ the last date is perfect

Comment: i have a last question ... (I just saw an exception during my test)
if i add a many column, i need concat if they are not identical (example in 1st post)

Comment: @Eolynas - So you need last rows per groups for all columns without `comment` ?

Comment: Yes, normally they will be the same.
Just for the column "code" I want to concat that if they are different
i have edit the 1st post

Comment: @Eolynas - Super, then change `.groupby('id')` to `.groupby(['id','code','col_example'])`

Comment: thx :), and for the column "code" ? (concat if  that if they are different)

Comment: so sorry ... i have again a exception (i have 43000 line ...)....
if "code" is different for the same id, is possible to concat (as comments)? exemple id=1 and code=CB25/CZ10 ?

Comment: @Eolynas - yes, then change `d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id','comments']), 'last')
d['comments'] = lambda x: ' // '.join(x.dropna())` to `d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id','comments', 'code']), 'last')
d['comments'] = lambda x: ' // '.join(x.dropna()) d['code'] = lambda x: ' // '.join(x.dropna())`